# Кастомный заголовок для Static Cells

Tags: swift

Я хочу менять заголовок (Header) для Static Cells в зависимости от состояния моего приложения, через переменную. Например:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    var headerText = "Header"
    if section == 0 {
        myVar ? (headerText = "HeaderText_1") : (headerText = "HeaderText_2")
    }
    return headerText
}
```

Но в процессе, независимо от значения моей переменной myVar, отображается только то значение headerText, которое определилось при первом запуске приложения. Как возможно влиять на это?

Answer (score 0):

Вы неверно используете тернарное выражение `? :`, оно предназначено для возвращения результата, внутри него нельзя присваивать выражения

Вам нужно переписать условие например так

```
if section == 0 {
    headerText = myVar ? "HeaderText_1" : "HeaderText_2"
}
```

**Дополнение**

Для обновления заголовка вызовите `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Все верно, но это никак не влияет на проблему, даже если я буду использовать if/else.

Comment: @sumrakss см дополнение

Comment: ```tableView.reloadData()``` вызывает черный экран и переполняет память.

Comment: @sumrakss тогда дополните вопрос кодом для воспроизведения проблемы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example